# How can I install a new xenserver dom0 kernel?

Tags: centos, xen, xenserver, citrix

Since Citrix released the full source code to xenserver 6.2 I've been evaluating it.
It's works very well, but there is only one problem that I haven't solved.

<strike>Unfortunately, Citrix do not supply the sources for the kernel in their DDK.
Therefore there is no way to compile the kernel version that isn't being used.</strike>
(Citrix provide kernel sources for them on the source ISO's downloadable separately)

So I compiled a new kernel.  But how do I upgrade the dom0 kernel in order to get these new kernel modules working and have all my hardware detected?

Under ubuntu I'd use update-grub. But grub is not being used here.

The rpm kernel install process also didn't work (the old kernel is still running up).

Does anyone know how to install a new kernel in dom0?

I have also placed this question on the Citrix support forums but there have been no answers forthcoming and very few views.  I'd appreciate some help, hints.  Maybe someone knows exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

XenServer does not use grub. Considering you are going outside the supported envelope, you might want to look into `/boot/extlinux.conf`.

Having installed your new RPMs, your new kernel should be available in `/boot/`.

Fix a new entry on `/boot/extlinux.conf` pointing to your new kernel. Make sure to leave a fallback in case your new kernel does not boot. That will make it easy to boot back into the original kernel and fix any issues.

Cheers

Felipe